# SQL Date Conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I'm looking to convert a date formate from yyyymmdd to mm dd yyyy

I found quite a [few](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258271%28v=SQL.80%29.aspx) [resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054%28SQL.80%29.aspx) of SQL statements. But I'm too new to really know what I'm looking for.

I have the following expression and I need it to shoot out the date

```
select Date_of_hire from Employee where employeeID='input'
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are not doing this in application code, where it belongs?

Comment: The application isn't native to the database I'm running queries from. I think I can only run basic sql queries and spit them out to an interface. I'm going to look into this to see if I can do it however. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run into this a few times importing data from a AS400 (date stored as string) into a sql table where there isn't any application in the middle to do the formatting, so I can see why you might want to do this.
Look into Cast and Convert() ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx )

```
select Convert(varchar,Cast(Date_of_hire as datetime) ,101) as Date_of_hire from Employee where employeeID='input'
```

This will format it like 01/01/2001.
The problem with convert is that it is really limited on how it formats it.
To get a date from a string like that, you may be able to leave convert out and just Cast as datetime.

Comment: Thanks, the cast and datetime was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

Choosing the date format is a job best done in the presentation layer (your forms app, your ASP app, your report etc). Let SQL simply return the `DATETIME` field and present it in whatever format you fancy by properly setting the output your app.

Comment: The application isn't native to the database I'm running queries from. So I'm not sure if I can do that. I'll look into this though. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), requested, 110), '-', ' ') AS hiredate
```

Take a look at http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx for further reference.  Note that this is equivalent to

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), requested, 101), '/', ' ') AS hiredate
```

Comment: convert won't actually change anything in the sql table will it?

Comment: Changes to the table only occur with a insert, update or delete command so a simple select cannot alter the data

Comment: It does not change anything in the SQL table.

Comment: Echoing Oded's comment on your question, you might be better to have the SQL select convert your data into a DateTime value, and have your user interface (or whatever is consuming your data) format the date as required.

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
select replace(convert(varchar, Date_of_hire, 101), '/', ' ') 
from Employee where employeeID='input'
```